# Python regex for url

Tags: python, regex

I need help to create regex for the url.

The part https://test/ is fixed and will be in all samples.

I want to to have regex which can have values after test between starting with a letter from a to j (case insensitive) and can have any digit or character after it.

Valid samples:

```
https://test/abacus/b/
https://test/horse/1/3/
```

Invalid samples:

```
https://test/zoo
```

so far I have tried:

```
^https://test/[a-j][a-zA-Z0-9]*$
```

Comment: regex101.com will help you..

Comment: try this regex `(?:https://test/)[a-j][a-zA-Z0-9]*\/(?:\d+\/|\w+\/){1,2}`

Comment: `https://test/[a-j]\S*`

Answer (score 0):

You are not matching the `/` in the character class. Matching all example strings, you can add the `/`:

```
^https://test/[a-j][a-zA-Z0-9/]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2S8V8W/1)

Matching at least a non whitespace char except for `/` in between:

```
^https://test/[a-j][^\s/]*(?:/[^\s/]+)*/?$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `https?://` Match the protocol with optional s
- `test/[a-j]` Match `test/` followed by a char in the range a-j
- `[^\s/]*` Match optional non whitespace chars other than `/`
- `(?:/[^\s/]+)*` Optionally repeat matching `/` and 1+ no whitespace chars other than `/`
- `/?` Match an optional `/`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z08nmc/1)